# C# Importing Excel files doesn't work anymore

Tags: c#, excel, windows-7

I have an application that imports sheets from Excel files and processes them. I started developing on Windows XP and all worked fine, but now I was forced to switch to Windows 7 Professional x86.

The problem that suddenly occurred is that when the application wants to open the Excel file, it throws an exception.

I didn't change anything in the code, I just switched the PC I work on. It works flawlessly on my private PC (Windows 7 Professional x64).

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What error you are getting ??

Comment: what is the exception that you get?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you checked file/folder access?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example piece of code I have used to read an excel spreadsheet.

You will also need to add references to "Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel"

Then the using "using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;" can be used to access the required objects.

```
string FileName = @"D:\Spreadsheet.xlsm"; 
MyApp = new Excel.Application();
MyApp.Visible = false;
MyBook = MyApp.Workbooks.Open(FileName, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
sheets = new List<excelsheet>();

for (int z = 1; z < MyBook.Sheets.Count + 1; z++)
{
    MySheet = (Excel.Worksheet)MyBook.Sheets[z];

    Excel.Range excelRange = MySheet.UsedRange;
    object[,] valueArray = (object[,])excelRange.get_ValueExcel.XlRangeValueDataType.xlRangeValueDefault);
}
```

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

I checked the original message of the exception, where it told me that the file could not be found at the provided path.

Apparently, the `Path.getFullPath(string filename)` function returned a different path for the file that I selected in an `OpenFileDialog`. This caused the file to be searched in the Debug folder of my application, while it resided in a sub folder of the project folder.

My solution now is to create the path manually, with the given file name, which works as great as ever.